# Print multiple images on click of one button print all in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have created multiple images into disk. I want click print all button and prints all the images print in one shot.

```
public void PrintGraph()
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintImageHandler);

    PrintDialog MyPrintDialog = new PrintDialog();

    if (MyPrintDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pd.Print();
    }
    myprintDocument.Dispose();
}
```

handler is below:

```
private void PrintImageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ppeArgs)
{
    Graphics g = ppeArgs.Graphics;
    for (int i = 0; i < lstAllImages.Count; i++)
    {
        Image objimage = Image.FromFile(lstAllloadImages[i].ToString());
        g.DrawImage(objimage, 0, 0, objimage.Width, objimage.Height);
    } // Draw Image using the DrawImage method 
}
```

Only one image is print. 
i want print multiple images at click on print all button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name of the event args object suggests ([PrintPageEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.aspx)), this event handler will be called once for each *page* that you're going to produce. It will be called again for a new page if you set the [HasMorePages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.hasmorepages.aspx) property to true.

Within this event, you can only control what appears on a single page, so your current code is writing all of the images on top of each other (presumably, they're all the same size, or the largest is last, or you'd have already noticed bits of earlier images showing up at the side or bottom of the last image).

So you have to track which image you're wanting to draw using some external fields. E.g. you'd have:

```
if (MyPrintDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    currentPage = 0;
    pd.Print();
}
```

And then in your event handler:

```
int currentPage;

private void PrintImageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ppeArgs)
{
    Graphics g = ppeArgs.Graphics;
    Image objimage = Image.FromFile(lstAllOperatorloadImages[currentPage].ToString());
    g.DrawImage(objimage, 0, 0, objimage.Width, objimage.Height);
    currentPage++;
    ppeArgs.HasMorePages = currentPage <  lstAllOperatorloadImages.Count;
}
```

To print two images per page, I'd probably do something like:

```
private void PrintImageHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ppeArgs)
{
    Graphics g = ppeArgs.Graphics;
    Image objimage = Image.FromFile(lstAllOperatorloadImages[currentPage].ToString());
    g.DrawImage(objimage, 0, 0, objimage.Width, objimage.Height);
    currentPage++;
    if(currentPage < lstAllOperatorloadImages.Count)
    {
        objimage = Image.FromFile(lstAllOperatorloadImages[currentPage].ToString());
        g.DrawImage(objimage, 0, 600, objimage.Width, objimage.Height);
        currentPage++;
    }
    ppeArgs.HasMorePages = currentPage <  lstAllOperatorloadImages.Count;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to print two images per page?

Comment: @user990897 - yes, of course, but you wouldn't want to `DrawImage()` them both at position `0,0` (otherwise, you'd still be drawing one on top of the other, and the last one drawn would "win")

Comment: Is this right? Graphics g = ppeArgs.Graphics; Image objimage = Image.FromFile(lstAllImages[currentPage].ToString()); if (currentPage % 2 == 0) { g.DrawImage(objimage, 0, 0, objimage.Width, objimage.Height); } else { g.DrawImage(objimage, 0, 600, objimage.Width, objimage.Height); currentPage++; } ppeArgs.HasMorePages = currentPage < lstAllImages.Count;

Comment: @user990897 - I've updated my answer for two images per page - You have to do everything you want to do for one page inside a single call to your `PrintImageHandler` method.

Comment: The above comment helped me more than anything.  I didn't grasp that the HasMorePages essentially made the print call recursive until reading it.